# Javascript: Concise way to fill sparse array with object

Tags: javascript, data-structures, syntax

I am using an array to store objects (directed edges between nodes) and would like to use the an array to store the objects such that I can use the index of the array to refer to the object id.

```
 /**
 * Take a graph where 
 * @param {number} N: The number of Nodes of in the graph
 * @param {number[][]} trust: an array of directed edges trust [[a,b]] draws 'a trusts b'
 * @return {number} 
 */
var findJudge = function(N, trust) {
    let nodes = [
        {
            trusts: {},
            trustedBy: {}
        }
    ]    

    trust.forEach(pair => {
        nodes[pair[0]].trusts = pair[1]
        nodes[pair[1]].trusted = pair[0]
    })    
    return -1
};
```

Sample input: `N = 2` and `trust = [[1,2]]` errors because `nodes[2]` doesn't exist yet at runtime.

I would like to avoid pre-filling the array with null values if possible in the event that N is a really large number.  Perhaps this is not the proper data structure for filling sparse adjacency lists.  Is there a way to say `var x = new Array(of type object, of length N)`?

Im open to any and all solutions.

Edit to show context of problem 
https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-town-judge/description/

Comment: Sample input and expected output would help to make your point clearer

Comment: Just check whether it exists and create it if it doesn't but you need it.

Comment: What is `N`? Where is it used?

Comment: I edited the question with a link for context of the variables in addition to sample input and output.

Comment: Please incorporate the context into the question. If that link goes down, this question remains without context.

Comment: as per @Bergi suggestion I simply check if object exists or not and create it.  Still curious to other suggestions if anyone has any other javascript wizardry
```
var findJudge = function(N, trust) {
    function node() {
        trusts: {}
        trustedBy: {}
    }
    let nodes = []

    trust.forEach(pair => {
        pair.forEach(element => {
            if (nodes[element] === undefined)
                nodes[element] = new node()
        })
        nodes[pair[0]].trusts = pair[1]
        nodes[pair[1]].trusted = pair[0]
    })    
    return -1
};
```

Comment: Apart from your question, please note that you would be overwriting the `trusts` and `trusted` properties when they already had a value. You cannot assume that a person only trusts one other person at the most. So, I think you need to review your idea.

Comment: Oh ya great point, Ya I didn't get to implementing that logic as I was just trying to get around the sparse array insertion and pass a trivial case.  but of course that is a great point to mention in regards to pushing to the list of trusts and trusted by rather than overwriting.  Thank you trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to avoid pre-filling the array with null values if possible in the event that N is a really large number.

You can avoid such extreme case by first checking the size of the `trust` argument. If there is a solution, then at least `trust.length >= N-1`.

If however that test passes, then you will anyway need to look at all entries of `trust` to determine whether there is a judge, and who it is. So then it does not increase the time complexity of the work if you also create all N nodes, before even iterating over `trust`.

Secondly, your code would currently overwrite information, so that you can only store one trusted person and one trusted-by person per node. What you really need is that `trusted` and `trustedBy` can store multiple entries; at least when you want to make a double-threaded graph.

But when you really think about it, you would have enough information if you would only know the *count* of `trusted` and the *count* of `trustedBy` a node has. The judge must be the one for which the `trusted` count is zero and the `trustedBy` count is N-1. There cannot be two of those, as that would be a contradiction.

So, you can avoid creating the graph. It is enough that you just store counts, that start with 0.

As in JavaScript array indices start with zero and not 1, your `nodes` array would be indexed by one less than the actual person-id that is used in the `trust` array.

Here is how that code could look:

```js
var findJudge = function(N, trust) {
  // Quick exit, to avoid unnecessary looping
  if (trust.length < N - 1) return -1;

  // Create all nodes (with index one less -- starting at 0)
  let nodes = Array.from({
    length: N
  }, () => ({
    trusts: 0,
    trustedBy: 0
  }));
  // Count trust relationships in both directions
  trust.forEach(([trustedBy, trusted]) => {
    nodes[trustedBy - 1].trusts++;
    nodes[trusted - 1].trustedBy++;
  });
  // The only judge meets the following requirements
  // Add one to the found judge to go from 0-based to 1-based.
  return nodes.findIndex(node => node.trusts == 0 && node.trustedBy == N - 1) + 1 || -1;
};

console.log(findJudge(3, [[1,2],[3,2],[1,3]]));
```

If you care about speed, then replace all loops with old-style `for` loops, and instead of the array of objects (`trust`), use *two* simple arrays of counts (`trusts` and `trustedBy`), as arrays of integers usually lead to better execution times than arrays of objects.

Answer (score 0):

as per @Bergi suggestion I simply check if object exists or not and create it.  Still curious to other suggestions if anyone has any other javascript wizardry

```
var findJudge = function(N, trust) {
    function node() {
        trusts: {}
        trustedBy: {}
    }
    let nodes = []

    trust.forEach(pair => {
        pair.forEach(element => {
            if (nodes[element] === undefined)
                nodes[element] = new node()
        })
        nodes[pair[0]].trusts = pair[1]
        nodes[pair[1]].trusted = pair[0]
    })    
    return -1
};
```

Would have posted this as a comment however comments don't allow for code block formatting.